# Are there any functions $f$ such that $f'$ is continuous, $f'(a)>0$ positive, but $f$ is not increasing on any interval containing $a$?

Tags: real-analysis

Can there exist a function that is continuously differentiable and has $f'(a)>0$ but is not increasing on any open interval containing $a$?

So I understand that we have that $f'$ is continuous and I was trying to use the fact that 
$$f'(a)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)}$$ but I'm not sure how to implement it!

Comment: Yes. If $f’(x)\lt 0$ for any other $x$ in that interval, then $f$ is not increasing in that interval.

Comment: If the derivative is continuous then $f'(a) \gt 0$ implies $f'(x) \gt 0$ on a neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: If you are asking if there exists an open interval around $a$ with this property, then no. $f'$ is continuous and positive at $a$, so it is positive on an open interval around $a$ (by continuity).

Comment: If you mean, must there there be some open interval containing $a$ on which $f$ is increasing, then the answer is "yes".  By continuity, $f'$ is positive on some open interval containing $a$, and $f$ is increasing on that interval.  This is different from the interpretation @Tavish gives, but I think it is likely the one intended.

Comment: @Tavish : if I understand correctly, I don't think OP is asking if this is true for *every* interval, just whether there exists such an interval.

Comment: @MPW I apologise- I was not clear in the question. I meant that it is not increasing on any open intervals containing a.

Comment: Thank @Michael I have done so now

Comment: Quick try: What about $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x) + (1/2)x$ (for $x\neq 0$) and $f(0)=0$. With $a=0$. Well this works without having $f'$ continuous.  If $f'$ is continuous there is no such counter-example.

Comment: @MPW Yes I know, I was trying to say that one can find such an interval, given a suitable $f$.